# Generate and deploy a JSP in Wildfly 9 during runtime

Tags: jsp, hotdeploy, wildfly-9

I am looking for a way to deploy a JSP during runtime into Wildfly 9. I have an EAR project which generates these jsp files in their uncompiled form based on a template, I am not going into depth with this as it's irrelevant. We are in the process of migrating from JBoss 4.2 which use to allow us writing these JSP's to the JBoss work directory. These JSP's were then picked up as being part of the EAR project, I could access the utilities within the EAR via scriptlets, it also allowed access to the custom tag libraries within the EAR. This was due to JBoss 4.2 extracting contents to the work directory and using that content to deploy. I know that it would be possible to explode the EAR in wildfly 9 so we can write these generated pages to the exploded EAR, but I don't want to go that route if possible. I am also aware of setting up a static resource directory which doesn't allow the functionality which is required. Now my question is, is it possible to have similar functionality within wildfly 9. I am looking for possibilities or ideas regarding this, for instance exploding another WAR project which doesn't form part of the EAR and deploying these resources into that exploded WAR for instance. Any suggestions are welcome.